# Unable to fetch text values present within strong tag using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, browser-automation, xpath, cross-browser-testing

While trying to print values present within the strong tag using XPath, I'm getting the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
> strong

This is my code:

```
   WebElement eleText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong"));
    
    String testerName = eleText.getText();
    System.out.println(testerName);
```

This is my webpage which I'm trying to get values within the strong tag:

```
<a id="id_109996" class="activity"> 
<strong>heizil</strong>: <label id="sample_label">
```

Expected output: heizil

If this is not the proper way, can anyone suggest any other way of getting the values present in the strong tag?

Comment: What is happening after : System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("strong")).getText());

Comment: thanks it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple workarounds to handle such scenarios while doing web automation using Selenium. While working in [outsourced software testing](https://www.qasource.com/) company and developing frameworks in multiple languages below is the most widely used approach -

```
WebElement eleText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity']/strong")).getText()
String testerName = eleText.getText();
System.out.println(testerName);
```

Comment: Thanks alot noted!

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

- I have tried accessing the element and get text successfully using

> System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("strong")).getText());

- Found working as expected
- Suggestion : Use the xpath as last option and choice. Its not most reliable strategy

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your xpath selector is too general, it is trying to locate any  tag on the page.

A more specific xpath selector can be used to locate the text "`heizil`":

```
WebElement eleText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='id_109996']/strong"));
String testerName = eleText.getText();
System.out.println(testerName);
```

This xpath selector finds the `<strong>` tag that is a direct child of the  tag with the id "`id_109996`".